# Error when trying to start rxconsole

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS and can't figure out why I can't start rxconsole. I'm simply going through the tutorials and everything went fine until now. When I type rxconsole I get the following error:

```
(rxconsole:4996): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rxconsole:4996): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rxconsole:4996): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rxconsole:4996): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[ERROR] [1348039963.832866342]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
```

And then it's just stuck there. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 in a virtual machine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44094/error-when-trying-to-start-rxconsole/) by [Kinna](https://answers.ros.org/users/3228/kinna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is roscore running? Try executing the following in a separate terminal:

```
roscore
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6